# Is this an explicit construction of a Hurwitz space with Galois group Z/p, p distinct branch points, and inertia group Z/(p-1)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-theory, hurwitz-theory

I am desperately confused and would like a sanity check that the following moduli space/stack is a Hurwitz space/stack. I would also appreciate any references on the topic of the explicit construction of a Hurwitz stack over fields other than $\mathbb{C}$. The only reference I could find is Wewer's thesis, a copy of which continues to elude me!

Let $\mathrm{Art}_k$ be the category of local artinian $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras. Let $H$ be the Hurwitz space over $\mathrm{Art}_k$ with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/p$ over $P^1$, with $p$ distinct branch points, and inertia group $Z/(p-1)$ over each branch point.

We now construct a moduli space $M$. The moduli space of deformations of the Artin-Schreier curve $y^{p-1} = x^p - x$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{p-1}}$ to $\mathrm{Art}_k$ with marked points. Let $A^{p-2} := \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[r_2, ..., r_{p-1}][\frac{1}{r_i}][\Delta^{-1}],$ where $\Delta$ is the discriminant of $y^{p-1} = x(x-1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_{p-1}).$

---

[image]

---

Some more commentary on this moduli functor: Let $G := \text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}_p[\mu^{\pm 1}, c] \simeq \mathbb{G}_m \rtimes \mathbb{G}_a$. The moduli functor $M_m$ may be represented by $$M := \text{Proj} A^{p-2} \times_G EG.$$ It is important to note that we enforce the morphisms of this curve to be continuous, meaning they fix the maximal ideal, i.e., they are automorphisms of the Artin-Schreier curve. These morphisms end up being lifts of the usual automorphism group of the Artin Schreier curve, $\Gamma := \mathbb{Z}/p \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)^2$, to the full family. In fact, $$M \simeq \text{Proj} A^{p-2} \times_\Gamma E\Gamma.$$ Let $\zeta$ be a $(p-1)^2$ root of unity. The generators of the automorphism group of our Artin-Schreier curve are $\sigma := (x+1, y)$ and $\tau := (\zeta^{p-1}x, \zeta^{p/(p-1)}y)$, and their lifts are $(-r_{p-1}x + r_{p-1}, y)$ and $(r_2x, (r_2)^{p/(p-1)}y)$ respectively.

---

Here is is my rough reasoning that inclines to me think that $M$ is $H$. We know that all $\mathbb{Z}/p$-Galois covers of $P^1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ are Artin-Schreier curves $x^p - x = f(y)$. I posit that $\mathbb{Z}/p$-Galois covers of $P^1$ over $\mathrm{Art}_k$ are deformations $x(x-1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_{p-1}) = f(y)$, forming a moduli space $N$. Further, if we wish to look at the moduli stack of families of curves with automorphism group $\Gamma := \mathbb{Z}/p \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)^2$, then this is the moduli stack $N$ restricted to covers s.t. the inertia groups of the branch points of the cover are all $Z/(p-1)$. Lastly, all covers with said inertia groups are $(p-1)$-sheeted covers of $P^1$, since the automorphism $\tau^{p-1}$ acts trivially on the branch points.

**Here's my question:** Is $M$ an explicit construction of $H$? What is the relationship between $M$ and $H$? Is $H$ far more complicated, and constructed in an entirely different fashion?

Comment: Hi Catherine, about Artin-Schreier covers, [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.08632) seems relevant. About Wewers thesis, if you email me I can send you a pdf, though I'm fairly sure his thesis does not talk about the moduli of Artin-Schreier covers. In general when I hear Hurwitz space, I immediately think about something defined over $Z[1/n]$, which basically forces you to talk about the tame case, since including wild stuff would result something that isn't even flat over $Z[1/n]$...

Comment: ...  For tame Hurwitz spaces, you can also try Bertin-Romagny's "Champs de Hurwitz" (and the citations therein, some of which also deal with wild ramification) and Abramovich-Corti-Vistoli's "Twisted bundles and admissible covers". Both are written in a modern language and work over $Z[1/n]$.

Comment: @WillChen The moduli space representing the deformation problem has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, so we can easily take them to be coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[1/(p-1)]$ instead. It seems that over these coefficients the wild stuff becomes tame. Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: In your definition of $H$, how can you have a $Z/p$ cover with inertia group $Z/(p-1)$?

Comment: In my question, I mentioned a char 0 order p and an order (p-1)^2 pullback action on coordinates, which would give a Z/p cover of P^1 with inertia group Z/(p-1), no?